# how to soft-separate cases inside a switch-case

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have a switch case that have 4 cases with the same general code, but I need to initialize variables differently for them:

```
 int a,b,c;
 switch(type)
 {
   case A:
   case B:
   case C: 
   case D:
     foo(a,b,c);
 }
```

What I have currently is something like `a = type == A ? 1 : 2;` and for a bit complex variable:

```
if(type == A)
  b = 1;
else if(type == B)
  b = 5;
else
  b = 2;
```

This works, but looks ugly in my opinion, and not very fluent. I can divide the cases entirely, but I want to avoid copy-paste in my code.

What I hope to do is something like:

```
 int a,b,c;
 switch(type)
 {
   case A:
     a = 1;
     b = 1;
   case B:
     a = 2;
     b = 5;
   case C: 
   case D:
     a = 1;
     b = 2;
     foo(a,b,c);
 }
```

But this obviously wouldn't work as `case D` variable assignment will happen even if the case was A or B. Is there a way to achieve this in a neat (and working :) way?

*edit:* the `switch` is actually to filter **other** cases, so I do want the `foo()` inside these specific 4 cases

Comment: `goto case D;`, but whether this is better structure is actually debatable.

Comment: Based on what you've got currently, why don't you put the call to `foo` outside of the switch, since it's called for all cases?

Comment: `break` is used to end cases. In case C, you omit it intentionally so that C "falls through" and does the same thing as D. I assume you probably want the `foo()` call outside the switch entirely? Is it really only for the C & D case?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I omitted the break from all cases, since I want them all to get to `foo` and I want `foo` inside the `switch` as I explained in my edit

Comment: It doesn't work that way. If you want all cases to get to `foo()`, then `foo()` goes outside the switch. If you want `foo()` not to run for some other cases, then you'll have to put an `if` around it for those cases. Don't fight the language...use the features it provides as they are meant to be used.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Can you go to a case label with a `goto`?  Not in standard C.  All else apart, case labels need not be unique in a function, so it could be ambiguous. Or maybe you were documenting “as if”.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't check thoroughly. You find such code, so there are compilers supporting it... what's definitely allowed is having another label inside the switch block, like in my answer.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I take your word for it.  I've not seen such code, nor felt a need to experiment with it to see if GCC allows it, for example.  Yes, your 'other label inside a switch' (as in your answer) is definitely kosher, witness the occasional typo `defualt:` label which can leave people wondering why switch doesn't handle the default case correctly.  I'm not yet convinced the example code is a good motivating example; it could too easily be handled better with separate calls to `foo()` and some `break` statements.  OTOH, this is probably a side-effect of creating an MCVE.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think it *might* be. As I commented on LeeDanielCrocker's answer, IMHO it depends on the *actual* code. With a huge switch (acting as a jump-table, IIRC I've seen something like this in an AVR simulator), it can improve code readability too keep related code snippets close to each other, using `goto`. With a "normal" sized `switch`, I'd look out for alternatives without `goto`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler btw, I observe here that *any* answer involving `goto` is downvoted by some. I guess that's the dogmatic "`goto` is bad" mindset. Well, I disagree. C offers a good set of dedicated control structures covering 99.9% of all use cases and `goto` is for the .1% where you want to have a different control flow and have good reasons for that. A huge switch with some branches sharing common code is one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your code, you could do something like this:

```
int a,b,c;
switch(type)
{
   case A:
     a = 1;
     b = 1;
     goto call_foo;
   case B:
     a = 2;
     b = 5;
     goto call_foo;
   case C: 
   case D:
     a = 1;
     b = 2;
   call_foo:
     foo(a,b,c);
     break;

   // [...] more cases
}
```

Your logic in this construct needs to be a bit more complex in order to justify *this* use of `goto`, IMHO.

Comment: Yeah... `goto` was the first thing I though of, but I hardly think its appropriate

Comment: @CIsForCookies it's used inside `switch` blocks sometimes, for exactly that purpose. But think about whether you really gain something in your actual code before doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Make it clear with an explicit control variable:

```
int a, b, c;
int run_foo = 1;

switch(type) {
case A:
  a = 1; b = 1;
  break;
case B:
  a = 2; b = 5;
  break;
case C: 
case D:
  a = 1; b = 2;
  break;
default:
  run_foo = 0;
  break;
}
if (run_foo) { foo(a,b,c); }
```

Comment: Depending on the *actual* code, this can be confusing. An example where you typically see `goto` inside `switch` are virtual CPUs supporting lots of opcodes. If the actual code is as simple as this example, avoiding `goto` is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

So you don't need to call `foo()` for type not in `{A, B, C, D}`, huh? The solution is simple then:

```
int a, b, c;
switch (type) {
case A:
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    break;
case B:
    a = 2;
    b = 5;
    break;
case C: 
case D:
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    break;
default:
    return;      // no foo() for this case
}

foo(a, b, c);
```

Comment: not sure how that solution is simple - it assumes the switch is the only code inside the function. What if there is more code after the switch that has to be executed by all values of `type`?

Comment: that's simple: just move this code to a separate "wrapper" for `foo()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid the hard breaks, except for case C, and using goto's in a switch statement; just leads to more and more spaghetti as maintainers follow suit.  If you're just trying to reduce the number of code lines in the switch, you can use a function or macro.

```
#define DoFooCase(_a, _b, _c) a = _a; b = _b; foo(a, b, _c);

switch(t) // Can't use type, it's keyword.
{
    case A:
        DoFooCase(1, 1, c);
        break;
    case B:
        DoFooCase(2, 5, c);
        break;
    case C:
    case D:
        DoFooCase(1, 2, c);
        break;
}
```